# Can we combine this steps in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I had written below steps, is their any way to combine these steps to make it smaller

```
With Sheets("StockInHandReport")
    .ListObjects("Stock_In_Hand").Range.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    .ListObjects("Stock_In_Hand").Range.AutoFilter
End With

With Sheets("StockInHandReport").ListObjects("Stock_In_Hand")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match("Assigned Location", .HeaderRowRange, 0), Criteria1:="<>*Nexa*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*Mumbai*"

End With
With Sheets("StockInHandReport")
    .Range("Stock_In_Hand[Model],Stock_In_Hand[SubModel Code],Stock_In_Hand[SubModel]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("DRSR Arena").Range("B6")
    
End With
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your `With` statements like this to make code adjustments easier.

```
With Sheets("StockInHandReport")
    With .ListObjects("Stock_In_Hand")
        .Range.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .Range.AutoFilter
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match("Assigned Location", .HeaderRowRange, 0), Criteria1:="<>*Nexa*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*Mumbai*"
    End With
    .Range("Stock_In_Hand[Model],Stock_In_Hand[SubModel Code],Stock_In_Hand[SubModel]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("DRSR Arena").Range("B6")
End With
```

Comment: It really solve my problem